# Firestore/Flutter - Save current user data to device locally

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to save current user data to local cache rather than calling it every time I call the menu. This is what I'm currently doing in the menu widget constructor:

```
BurgerMenu() {
       color = Colors.black;
       FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) async {
         return Firestore.instance
             .collection('users')
             .document(value.uid)
             .get()
             .then((userData) {
                 email = userData.data["email"];
                 name = userData.data['name'];
             });
       });
  }
```

Email and Name is to add additional info when popping up the menu. I'm also not sure if this is the best practice for admin apps

Comment: Use shared preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to do that. Firestore cache the data on your behalf automatically for mobile apps but if you want to enable it for web app you can call the enablePersistence method.

for more info about caching for firestore check this doc[1]

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline